# POST XML value in AJAX without changing format of XML

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I have written code in jQuery to post XML data and send it to the server. Here is my code:

```js
function getByIDNumber() {
  var strXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><serviceRequest><role>DOFA</role><token>eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1aWQiOiJoYXJpc2hzYWh1IiwiZW1wbG95ZWVUeXBlIjoiUiZEU3RhZmYiLCJvdSI6Iml0aXMiLCJkaXNwbGF5TmFtZSI6IkhhcmlzaCBLdW1hciBTYWh1IiwicmFuZG9tTnVtYmVyIjoiNTgxNDI3NzAiLCJJRE51bWJlciI6IjQxODAwMDYwIn0=.KJcGC0R3KgMPLEyjkzZLEpmNSlVWmGKSS75YN0T4lzM=</token><serviceName>ProfileService</serviceName><operationName>EditProfile</operationName><parameters><parameter name="IDNUMBER" value="NDE4MDAwMTA=" /></parameters><hashCode>lR6eCMXjNovUQRmsqviqtYNG1JIZoJ7/N1+Z/nZKhY4=</hashCode></serviceRequest>';  
  alert(strXML);
  console.log(strXML);
  
  $.ajax({
    url: "index.php?pid=effi_cs",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    async: true,
    data: {
      strXML
    },
    success: function(re) {
      alert("success: alert");
    },
    error: function(re) {
      $("#response").html(re);
      alert(JSON.stringify(re));
    }
  });
}
```

When I check same XML on the server side Java page I get XML as below:

```text
strXML=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%3CserviceRequest%3E%3Crole%3EDOFA%3C%2Frole%3E%3Ctoken%3EeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1aWQiOiJoYXJpc2hzYWh1IiwiZW1wbG95ZWVUeXBlIjoiUiZEU3RhZmYiLCJvdSI6Iml0aXMiLCJkaXNwbGF5TmFtZSI6IkhhcmlzaCBLdW1hciBTYWh1IiwicmFuZG9tTnVtYmVyIjoiNTgxNDI3NzAiLCJJRE51bWJlciI6IjQxODAwMDYwIn0%3D.KJcGC0R3KgMPLEyjkzZLEpmNSlVWmGKSS75YN0T4lzM%3D%3C%2Ftoken%3E%3CserviceName%3EProfileService%3C%2FserviceName%3E%3CoperationName%3EEditProfile%3C%2FoperationName%3E%3Cparameters%3E%3Cparameter+name%3D%22IDNUMBER%22+value%3D%22NDE4MDAwMTA%3D%22+%2F%3E%3C%2Fparameters%3E%3ChashCode%3ElR6eCMXjNovUQRmsqviqtYNG1JIZoJ7%2FN1%2BZ%2FnZKhY4%3D%3C%2FhashCode%3E%3C%2FserviceRequest%3E
```

I am able to encode it but how to remove "strXML=" from xml data.

```
strXML=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><serviceRequest><role>DOFA</role><token>eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1aWQiOiJoYXJpc2hzYWh1IiwiZW1wbG95ZWVUeXBlIjoiUiZEU3RhZmYiLCJvdSI6Iml0aXMiLCJkaXNwbGF5TmFtZSI6IkhhcmlzaCBLdW1hciBTYWh1IiwicmFuZG9tTnVtYmVyIjoiNTgxNDI3NzAiLCJJRE51bWJlciI6IjQxODAwMDYwIn0=.KJcGC0R3KgMPLEyjkzZLEpmNSlVWmGKSS75YN0T4lzM=</token><serviceName>ProfileService</serviceName><operationName>EditProfile</operationName><parameters><parameter name="IDNUMBER" value="NDE4MDAwMTA=" /></parameters><hashCode>lR6eCMXjNovUQRmsqviqtYNG1JIZoJ7/N1+Z/nZKhY4=</hashCode></serviceRequest>
```

Comment: The format hasn't been changed, it's just URL encoded so that it's safe for transport. In your server side code there should be methods of decoding the value.

Comment: may you please tell how to decode it in java

Comment: I have no idea as I'm not a Java dev, however [this is a start](https://www.google.com/search?q=url+decode+string+in+java)

Comment: "When I check same XML on the server side Java page" please [edit] your question to show the code you're using to read it.

Comment: this works for me in java java.net.URLDecoder.decode(inputXML)

Comment: now how to extract only xml part or remove "strXML=" .